# Importing constants out of C++ headers instead of hardcoding them: extending .net controls?

Tags: c++, .net, windows, vb6

I've been researching how to extend .net controls to have more freedom to do the same things you can do with the regular windows API in C++ in a VB program. For example, if you want to add week numbers to a calendar control, you'll have to manually import the DLL and extend the control's class, calling internal windows functions.

I've found various topics on how people handle this, and I'm not quite happy with the 'canonical method'. To be honest, I think it's a pretty bad paradigm to use.

These internal windows functions use pointers to set magic properties.

First, I find it rather strange that a pointer, which its system-dependent value size, is being abused to hold something that isn't a memory location but a value, but that aside: these pointers are also used to set which attribute is being set.

For example, (leaving out all the boilerplate necessary to link up the code), changing the first day of the week to Tuesday would use this code:

```
Private Const MCM_FIRST As Int32 = &H1000
Private Const DTM_FIRST As Int32 = &H1000
Private Const DTM_GETMONTHCAL As Int32 = (DTM_FIRST + 8)
Private Const MCM_SETFIRSTDAYOFWEEK As Int32 = (MCM_FIRST + 15)
Dim hMonthView As IntPtr =
        SendMessage(Me.Handle, DTM_GETMONTHCAL, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)
Call SendMessage(hMonthView, MCM_SETFIRSTDAYOFWEEK, 0&, 1&)
```

So the magic values of `0x1008` and `0x1015` is what my question is about in this code.

First off, this is a rather strange way of working: these values aren't documented anywhere as far as I know other than the examples. What if I need a property where there happens to not be an internet tutorial on so far? Where/how do I find the value of `MCM_<ARBITRARY_VALUE_HERE>` in general?

Note: I mean the latter question in the broad, general sense: not applying to just the specific calendar control the example is about, but really any windows control. I can already google up the specific C++ header file by name (e.g. for the example it's defined in `Commctrl.h`: it's just that that piece of information is rather useless if I don't know the idiomatic way of how to pull something like that out of the C++ header into the VB code.

Secondly... these values are defined in headers somewhere. Is it not possible to import the values from the proper header? This way the program will stay working in the (admittedly unlikely) scenario where the DLL is changed by re-compiling it.

Comment: .Net does not support headers so your always going to need to provide the underlying values yourself.  All the Windows Controls are well documented, E.g. [Month Calendar Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/bumper-month-calendar-control-reference-messages) & include the name of the relevant header.  http://pinvoke.net can be useful. (Install the Windows SDK (may already be part of your VS install) for local copies of the headers)

Comment: Although the topic and documentation linked by @AlexK would be applicable to VB6, it would appear to me that your question isn't directly about VB6?  Similarly, your example code is VB.net, not VB6. So the `VB6` tag probably isn't appropriate for this post?

Comment: There might be an "XY problem" here ... you are 
asking about C++ headers but the real goal seems to be to learn how to best access / reference details of the Windows API...  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

One approach for this back for VB6 was to prepare a `TLB` file with constants, function declarations, etc. of the Win32 API, and then reference that in the VB6 program. The `TLB` didn't provide COM objects, it was just a convenient way of packaging up all the declarations as though they were in (what we now think of as) an assembly.

As far as I can think, that approach should still work perfectly well today in .NET through "COM" interop. You can just as easily reference the TLB in a C# or VB project and thereby access its contents.

The book [Hardcore Visual Basic by Bruce McKinney](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1572314222) included a disk with a prepared TLB for this purpose, and this seems to still be available today:

http://vb.mvps.org/hardweb/mckinney2a.htm

I don't know how comprehensive this was at the time, nor if it is really still up to date. At the very least it seems instructive in how to prepare a TLB for this type of approach.

---

The following page also provides a description of this approach with some additional explanation an examples (too long to copy in here).

http://www.brainbell.com/tutors/Visual_Basic/newfile156.html